# Let $a\in \mathbb{R}$. Show that $\frac{\lfloor na \rfloor}{n} \to a$ for $n\to \infty$

Tags: real-analysis

I am completely stumped when it comes to that question. Any impulses?

Comment: Hint: $na-1\leq \lfloor na \rfloor \leq na$

Comment: @Analysis Use squeezing theorem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Solving a sequence limit with floor](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2694064/solving-a-sequence-limit-with-floor)

Answer (score 4):

By squeezing

$$\frac{na}{n}\le\frac{\lfloor na\rfloor}{n} <\frac{na+1}{n}.$$

If you prefer,

$$a\le\frac{\lfloor na\rfloor}{n} <a+\frac{1}{n}.$$

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:** Notice that $0\le na-\lfloor na \rfloor \lt 1$ for all $n\in\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 0):

For each integer $n$, there are $0<\epsilon_n<1$ such that $\lfloor na \rfloor=na+\epsilon_n$, so $\frac{\lfloor na \rfloor}{n}=a+\frac{\epsilon_n}{n}\to a$ as $n\to \infty.$